# How to select (and copy) a text in display:table with Internet Explorer 8 or 9

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Let's have this simplified page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div style="display:table">
            <span>Try to copy me!</span>
            <br/>
            <textarea> Paste here! </textarea>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

In Internet Explorer 8 and 9 it is not possible to select and copy the text "Try to copy me!" or parts of it to the clipboard by using the mouse and Ctrl+C. (Ignoring the hack by selecting the text area also)

Unfortunately due to my complex page structure the display:table needs to stay in that place.

**My Question**: is it somehow possible to add CSS style to the span (or a additional inserted div) to make it possible to select the text again?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You don't wan't people to be able to select the text?

Comment: Works fine for IE9 in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/04wvhcf7/1/). Are there any other conditions we need to know about?

Comment: You could try putting a div with `display:table-cell` around the span and textarea, but like I said, it works here, so I can't test if that works better.

Comment: I wonder if there is a meta-tag in the head that doesn't allow to select the text.

Comment: I clarified the question, I want to be able to select the text, although of the display:table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mr Lister was right:
a display:table-cell enables the text selection again for me.

Here is what works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html
<html>
    <body>
        <div style="display:table">
            <span style="display:table-cell">Try to copy me!</span>
            <br/>
            <textarea> Paste here! </textarea>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```